# Getting a count on how many custom annotations are added to a mapView swift 4

Tags: swift, annotations, mapkit

I feel like this is something simple that I am just over looking. I have a map that the user pushes a button to add an annotation.

```
   func addPinToPath() {

    let catchPathPin = CatchAnnotation()

    let catchLat = map.userLocation.coordinate.latitude
    let catchLon = map.userLocation.coordinate.longitude

    catchPathPin.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: catchLat, longitude: catchLon)
    catchPathPin.title = "Fish On"
    catchPathPin.subtitle = "Path"
    catchPathPin.annoID = annoIDStart
    catchPathPin.pinImageName = "catch"

    let idToPass = catchPathPin.annoID

    annoIDCatch = idToPass!

    print(annoIDCatch)

    map.addAnnotation(catchPathPin)

    bitesInRoute = catchPathPin


}
```

at this point I would like to have a counter that shows in the display as to how many annotations are added.

annotations.count will give me a count of all annotations, but I only want the count for CatchPathPin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theres two options. You could have a count variable that you increment every time 
`addPinToPath` is called. The other option is to filter the current annotations and get the count from there.

```
count = map.annotations
    .filter { $0 is CatchAnnotation }
    .count
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. If you don't mind, how would I set up the count variable? That's more on the line of what I wanted to use. I really appreciate your time

Comment: something like this?  private var fish = 0

@IBAction func addPin(sender: UIButton) {
    fish += 1
    scoreLabel.text = "\(fish)"
} . ?